# Can't get why same dropdown's have different width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my trouble in screenshots:

first-dropdown:

[image]

second-dropdown:

[image]

Second dropdown has width a little bigger at right side. Google Chrome says, that width are 
the same.

HTML code:

```
<div class="row menu">
 <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
       data-toggle="dropdown">
      My reports
      <span class="caret my-reports-caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><%= link_to "Performance", performance_reports_path %></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Account settings", '#' %></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul> 
<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
       data-toggle="dropdown">
      My account
      <span class="caret my-account-caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><%= link_to "My website", websites_path  %></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Account settings", edit_user_registration_path(current_user) %></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.menu{
width:940px;
height: 30px;
border-width:1px;
border-top-style:solid;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-color: grey;
padding:10px;
background-color: rgb(212,229,190);
}
.row .nav-pills
.dropdown-menu {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
z-index: 1000;
display: none;
float: left;
min-width: 245px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
rgb(180, 210, 135)
background-color: #ffffff;
border-width:0 1px 1px 1px;
border-color:rgb(180, 210, 135);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(180, 210, 135, 0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(180, 210, 135, 0.2);
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(180, 210, 135, 0.2);
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
-moz-background-clip: padding;
background-clip: padding-box;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
}
```

**Added css of links**

```
.menu .nav-pills
.dropdown-menu a {
display: block;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-left: 10px;
clear: both;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 18px;
color: black;
white-space: nowrap;
}



.menu .nav-pills .dropdown-toggle {
border: 1px solid #B4D287;
background-color: white; 
margin-bottom: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: Give it fixed width. in CSS I only see min-width, but not `width: 245px;`,

Comment: there is no `selectbox` in given HTML, you are changing `ul li` to selectbox

Comment: @ShogunArts.de result of setting width: i.imgur.com/GB4S5.png

Comment: yeah, cause the a tag in your image has the width 245, not the dropdown-menu.

Comment: Another thing, whats the width of the class dropdown-toggle?

Comment: You are right - they are different! One is 247 and other is 246, but I can't set width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.row .nav-pills .dropdown-menu a {
    width:245px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

And add the width of the class="dropdown-toggle" to the `.row .nav-pills .dropdown-menu` in your CSS

**Edited CSS:**

```
.row .nav-pills .dropdown-menu {
    border-width:0 1px 1px 1px;   
    width: 243px;
}
.menu .nav-pills .dropdown-menu a { 
    padding-top: 5px; 
    height: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 235px;
} 

.menu .nav-pills .dropdown-toggle { 
    border: 1px solid #B4D287; 
    width:243px;
}
```

Maybe this should do it.

Comment: O_o when you add the CSS the a-tag is bigger than 245px? Ahh maybe cause of padding/margin. Subtract the padding/margin from 245px and add this number to the .row .nav-pills .dropdown-menu a

Comment: Ok, if I change css of a tag to match 245px, but border is drawing around dropdown menu, and it will stay the same ? or I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you should set a fixed width

Answer (score 0):

Add a `max-width: 245px;` property to your class `.dropdown-menu` it should fix the render.

Comment: Try to specify it to your `li` directly and if it doesn't work you still can create a new class to adjust the size of this specific dropdown

Comment: Do you mean - change width of li ?

Comment: Yes `li`'s which are in the `ul` class `dropdown-menu`

Answer (score 0):

I checked and found that any of the following style changes will be helpful instead of using :min-width".

.row .nav-pills
.dropdown-menu

{

```
   width: 245px;
```

}

OR

.row .nav-pills
.dropdown-menu

{

```
  width: 27.22%
```

}

for safety add max-width style.

Comment: Problem is in dropdown-toggle. They are different sizes.

Comment: In your question the style for
dropdown-toggle is not mentioned.
Please give me the style for dropdown-toggle, then I will check.

Comment: I solved this problem by setting width of dropdown-toggle. Thanks for trying help. Now I have another problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344570/my-dropkick-plugins-dropdown-looking-strange.