# My dropkick plugin's dropdown looking strange

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins

My dropkick look strange - https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIh6k.png

Container is bigger, than dropdown list.

My html:

```
 <div class="text_over_field">   
    <b>Your language preferences</b>
    <b>This is language you would like Print-it-Green service to be displayed in</b>
  </div>
<div class="field">
    <div class="dk_container dk_theme_default" id="dk_container_color" tabindex="7"  style="display: block; ">
        <a class="dk_toggle" style="width: 149px; ">
            <span class="dk_label">English</span></a>
        <div class="dk_options" style="top: 29px; ">
            <ul class="dk_options_inner">
                <li class="dk_option_current"><a data-dk-dropdown-value="">English</a></li>
                <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="#E15A01">Israeli</a></li>
                <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="#604A42">Ukrainian</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="submit" >
</div>
```

[Check the **CSS** markup](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/86122402/files/application.css)

[Check the **HTML** markup](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/86122402/files/form.htm)

All is wrapped in form_for_new class.
Also, it crashed my form.

What you can say about it ?

Comment: Could you show the **CSS** markup?

Comment: I didn't change from default css dropkick...http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/ - here you can download it. in examples they're normal.

Comment: And what about the **CSS** of your site? Maybe it's overwriting the values of the `DropKick`

Comment: I will give you a link to all my css.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/86122402/files/application.css - it is a lot of text

Comment: @Luis Sánchez, are you here ?

Comment: I'm not be able to reproduce your error... show me your html code, including your `<form></form>` tag

Comment: @Luis Sánchez,https://dl.dropbox.com/u/86122402/files/form.htm

Comment: It's working perfect with all your markups, http://jsfiddle.net/UL4Tu/5/ , the last thing i need is your javascript, but so far, I can't reproduce the error

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xqnveabun50e9ju/fohhWjrrpY. Maybe Bootstrap is crashing it or it is impossible ?

Comment: Maybe, if you can, put it all together and publish the site, but we need to see the error in order to fix it.

Comment: Do you mean just deploy somewhere or you want to see all code ?

Comment: can you give me your email, I will send you a link ?