# My dropkick jquery list look not correct

Tags: html, css, jquery-plugins

I have already asked this, but can't find reason of my problem( [My dropkick plugin's dropdown looking strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344570/my-dropkick-plugins-dropdown-looking-strange) )

For some reason it looks like this -> [image]

I can't get why, but my code is working correct in jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/UL4Tu/5/

Here is my html:

```
         <select name="fashion" class="default" tabindex="2">
     <a class="dk_toggle" style="width: 245px; ">
          <option value="Fashion">Fashion</option>
          <option value="Health">Health</option>
          <option value="Travel">Travel</option>
          <option value="Food">Food</option>
          <option value="Coupons">Coupons</option>
        </select>
```

My js:

```
       $('.default').dropkick();
```

My application.css file: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/86122402/files/application.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey now problem is that i think you **don't** used **css reset** please used this

**more info**  http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

used to this

```
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
fieldset,img { 
    border:0;
}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var {
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
ol,ul {
    list-style:none;
}
caption,th {
    text-align:left;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
q:before,q:after {
    content:'';
}
abbr,acronym { border:0;}
```

Comment: I put this in the start of my application.css and it didn't change nothing, or I'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: Could I delete something from that ?

Comment: if your upload to all code and create a link when i check to live problem than i help you definitely now please upload your code in your personal domain and send me link of your page

Comment: Thanks for help!
Sorry, that I behave like a child. I almost done to reverse my css and deleted unnecessary code. Now, I want to ask you how to change my dk_toggle width, because now it looks like : http://i.imgur.com/PvBYA.png

Comment: Now you can inspect element in browser developer tools and check to how much with of your dk_toggle and same width apply to your parent and child div